# Use of prepositions — "shocked with/by/for his death"

Tags: prepositions

As a Spanish speaker English prepositions are most of the time a nightmare; this is due to the fact that they do not have an accurate translation and also they have different aplications and meaning.

What preposition is correct in the following sentence?

> People were shocked **[ with | by | for ]** his death.

Comment: "People were shocked by his death" is most idiomatic.

Comment: @claudio sepulveda All prepositions in English prepositional phrases or phrasal verbs can be translated perfectly well into Spanish. People were shocked by his death. La gente se sorprendió con su muerte. Vaya, hombre. :)

Comment: Dear Lambie, Thank you for your comment, and based on this comment I´s kike to aske this: Can you give only one translation for prepositions such as: BY - examples: "People were shocked BY his death"  -  I go to work BY car  -  I left my bag BY the window.

Comment: No, but the reverse is true also. Just because not every preposition in English is the same one in Spanish does not mean every preposition in English cannot be ***accurately*** translated into Spanish. In Spanish, there is the preposition EN everywhere and it is not always IN in English either. It works both ways. EN este aspecto, el libro es interesante. Le vi EN la playa. EN lo que se refiere a este tema, no estoy de acuerdo. THAT aspect of the book is interesting, I saw him AT the beach. WITH regard to this subject, I don't agree. :) Welcome to the particular genius of a language. :)

Comment: Lambie I forgot: Do you have only one translation into Spanish for the preposition FOR.  examples: I was angry with my wife FOR buying a new car.  -  I am leaving FOR England next week. Thanks Lambie.

Comment: Besides, you didn´t give me your translations into Spanish for the preposition BY  (I mean ONE translation)

Comment: Claudio I gave examples the other way around. Prepositions have to be translated IN context. Not as single words. Look in any dictionary. By car is EN coche o en carro and by the window is cerca de la ventana. Your idea about single word translation for prepositions in either directions used in sentences is erroneous. Anyway, this is not a translation forum so let's leave it at that.

Comment: @Lambie: In that case, your original comment is totally unhelpful!

Comment: My original comment was that all preps. can be translated ***accurately*** into Spanish. And all Spanish ones can be translated into English. Both, in the context of sentences and utterances. Now, if you want dictionary entries, look in a dictionary. Preps. are part of longer syntagmas (phrases). But be my guest, try to disprove what I said.

Comment: Dear Lambie, (and I´m done with this), you say that pep. can be translated according  to the context, I agree, but what I meant in my original question is totally the opposite! In some cases and according to your own stand prep. have MORE than one translation into spanish and therefore different meanings, which makes it quite complicated to explain a student how to chose and use those prep. It seems Lambie you miss the point all together and therefore I have to agree with toniK that your comments have not been very helpful. I thank you just the same.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "by" is the correct preposition - "People were shocked by his death." I agree,  English can be a little confusing.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. On this site, we strive to *explain* answers, not merely state them. *Why* is *by* the correct preposition here? How is the meaning changed when the other prepositions are used? What are some real-life examples of usage? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @TapaDiptiSitaula feel free to edit your answer.  If you improve it, we can upvote it.